# Calculating Values from Various Files

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to calculate the value of a number of attribute tables as shown below (Using the graphic modeler). In the first image, I outline the process whereby I have three polygons and a point feature, each with a row of values derived from calculations such as number of points inside polygon and does the point intercept polygon XYZ.

Essentially, I need to add predefined values seen in the table in image 2 to the number in each cell then add these together to get a total for each shapefile and point feature. I then need to calculate the SUM value of all the shapefiles and point features as a cumulative value.

The table of values which are used for the calculation may need to be edited before running the script but will otherwise remain as default.

I have attempted to simplify this in the images below.

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Comment: hmm...if I get this right, I doubt that the field-calculator (or even QGIS for that matter) is the proper choice for what you want (strictly speaking this is not even a question with a geographical relation I guess, except for the presence of shapefiles). there is no reasonable way to actually 'save' those totals/sums after you (might be able to) calculate them in QGIS. since you are talking about a script, doing this in e.g. python could be the better choice. you can even open (but only save as excel file AFAIK) .dbf files associated with each shapefile as spreadsheets in excel.

Comment: I think what you are after is the join by attribute tool https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/joinattributestable.html.